# Head lamp identification

Tags: headlight

Does anyone know from which car is this head lamp?

[image]

Comment: Not mine :)  Presumably you want to know the make and model.  I would have thought that there will be a manufacturers symbol/mark on it somewhere or even a part number.  That would help a lot.

Comment: Also, where are you in the world? Knowing if the general location is South Africa or Norway might make a difference in identifying what we're looking at.

Comment: Further photos from different angles could help

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an inexpensive aftermarket knockoff. I don't see the ribbing in the housing I'd expect for an Original Equipment Manufacturer (OEM) product. The glue track doesn't include alignment cues I'd expect to see. I doubt this lamp seals well when it rains. I also don't understand the straight line cutoff at the right. Is that just a bandsaw cut? Its definitely not legal for USA market, no side markers, etc..Not sure which country allows that amber bulb without diffuser. I'm assuming that amber bulb is a parking lamp. My guess is Far East but not Japan; their lamp rules are insane.

I would like to see ALL the markings stamped and/or molded on the outside of the housing.  Part #'s, Spec #s, Cavity and molding #'s including the molded in date codes.  All of that information tells a whole lot... but in this case I'm guessing you won't find anything. And if so, that fact confirms it's an aftermarket knockoff.  Inexpensive lamp, not to code anywhere.

Another hint is the headlamp aim mechanism. Seeing that would tell us a whole lot.  Generally a manufacture picks a system, sticks with it and uses it EVERYWHERE.  If this lamp has no aim mechanism, that would clinch it as a VERY inexpensive aftermarket knockoff.

One more indicator.  All headlamps MUST include some sort of mechanism to allow the cavity to breath, but not include water.  Remember lamps get hot, and hot air expands.  I've seen designs that use Gortex patch, macaroni elbows, molded in air inlet channels.  Like the headlamp aim, most manufacturers tend to use the same system for that everywhere. How does this lamp allow air in and out?  On an aftermarket lamp you won't find a breathing system.  They just leak.